# zf2 default validation messages not overriding

Tags: zend-framework2, message, default, overriding

```
            $inputFilter->add(array(
            'name' => 'nightCharges',
            'required' => FALSE,
            'filters' => array(
                array('name' => 'Digits'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'GreaterThan',
                    'options' => array(
                        'min' => 1,
                        'messages' => array(
                            \Zend\Validator\GreaterThan::NOT_GREATER => 'My message',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

Above is my code snippet for validation in this case for 'check box'. If I set 'required' to "true" and submit empty form, it shows me the default 'Value is required and can't be empty' message and if I set 'required' to 'false' it does't show me any error at all. Even if I submit non digit value it doesn't show me actual error message.
Where am I making mistake?
Actually I was working on 'Please accept the terms & conditions' check box.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `GreaterThan` validator, try using `Identical` to ensure the value can't be anything other than `1`.

```
'validators' => array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Identical',
        'options' => array(
            'token' => '1',
            'messages' => array(
                Identical::NOT_SAME => 'Please accept the terms & conditions.',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you Svengali. But my main problem was because of the filters. Once I removed them the code seems to work fine, at least for now the messages are working as per my command. Will let you know if that really solved the problem for me. Take care